# Symfony validator conditional validation

Tags: php, symfony, validation, symfony-validator

```
 * @Assert\Type(type="array")
 * @Assert\Count(
 *     min=5,
 *     max=10
 * )
```

I need validate a type array and then I need to validate if the array has a min and max count.

But when I send a string value, then `Assert\Type` evaluates that's not a valid type, but despite that validation continues to `Assert\Count` and there is problem it is not an array and `Assert\Count` throw `UnexpectedValueException` and I have message: `This value should be of type {{ type }}.`, and the that's not the correct validation message for me.

Is possible do `Assert\Count` only when is `Assert\Type` condition correct?

Comment: Please rephrase to understand your question. So your property value could either be a string OR an array? And in case of an array it needs to be of specific length? I am pretty sure you'll require a [Custom Validation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) for it.

Comment: If i am understanding the question, then you are looking for [Assert Sequentially](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Sequentially.html) so it will throw the type error first then stop..

Comment: Bossman, thx this is solution,
But simple asserts I have in my project in more places.
Is there some solution for add `@Assert\Sequentially` as default?

Comment: @user2219071 you could look into validation groups and create a [Group Sequence Providers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/sequence_provider.html#group-sequence-providers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am understanding your question then using [Assert Sequentially](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Sequentially.html) is the resolution.

Update your Asserts to look like this:

```
 * @Assert\Sequentially({
 *     @Assert\Type(type="array"),
 *     @Assert\Count(min=5, max=10),
 * })
 */
```

The first validation will be raised if your *Type* is not an array and not perform any further validations.